# Boto3 get_bucket_location returns: Access Denied when using variable

Tags: for-loop, variables, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a file with a list of S3 buckets. I want to iterate over them to get in what region a bucket resides.

However, I'm getting this error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied

This is my code:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

with open('test','r') as input_file:

    for var in input_file:

        x = var.rstrip('\n')

        response = client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=x)

        print(x)
```

If I hardcode a bucket name inside (Bucket='bucket_name') it just works so it's not about permissions (and I confirm I've given all required permissions previously)

Why I can't use a variable in this simple code? And why I'm getting Access Denied?

Answer (score 1):

As per boto3 documentation, "Access Denied" is returned when there is a permission's issue. However real life showed me this problem might also appear when the referenced bucket name doesn't exist.

In my case I had a typo in the first bucket's name on my list, so, for boto, that bucket didn't exist throwing out the error msg.

FYI.